# How to hide Facebook login page if user is already log in?

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I have a main page where there are two buttons: Facebook login and email login. After login through one of these, the user will enter into application. So my question is if the user is already loged in through Facebook or email, how can I make it not show the main page bit direct to the inner page? This page is on main view controller. Could I hide this page if user is already loged in?

Answer (score 0):

If using javascript sdk you can check if user is logged in and connected to your app using **FB.getLoginStatus**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: This question is tagged with `objective-c`, I don't think that he uses the JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the user status in your Main View Controller before you show any view.
If not logged in, present the Login View.
If already logged in, present the Application View.

Comment: You think? Are you not sure if this is an answer?

Comment: This page is my main page in main view controller where can i check the Facebook session is valid or not .some example code will help me.i think i will check it in  application did finish lunch.